# : for displaying all elements in a multidimensional array in python 3.1

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a multidimensional array in python like:

```
arr = [['foo', 1], ['bar',2]]
```

Now, if I want to print out everything in the array, I could do:

```
print(arr[:][:])
```

Or I could also just do print(arr).  However, If I only wanted to print out the first element of each box (for arr, that would be 'foo', 'bar'), I would imagine I would do something like:

print(arr[:][0])

however, that just prints out the first data blog (['foo', 1]), also, I tried reversing it (just in case):

print(arr[0][:])

and I got the same thing.  So, is there anyway that I can get it to print the first element in each tuple (other than:

```
for tuple in arr:
    print(tuple[0])
```

)?  Thanks.

Comment: Just an explanation: Your `print(arr[:][:])` takes all items from all items from arr. It's functionally equivalent with `print(arr)`, `print(arr[:])`, `print(arr[:][:][:])` and `print(arr[:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:][:])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose the array, e.g.

```
>>> list(zip(*arr))[0]
('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 2):

zip() will be a little slower than your original solution. If you don't like your original solution because it requires multiple lines of code you can always do this:

```
[i[0] for i in arr]
```

zip() has a for loop inside so you cannot be faster than a for loop using zip().

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a misunderstanding about how python parses the indexing. You can tack as many `[:]` onto the array as you like and you'll get the same thing back.

```
>>> arr = [['foo', 1], ['bar',2]]
>>> print arr[:][:][:][:]
[['foo', 1], ['bar', 2]]
```

The second `[]` only indexes into the second dimension when you return an actual list-like object. It sounds like you want Matlab syntax like `arr[:,0]` which you'll need to use something like numpy.